# Rails, Select2 and Ransack return emprty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, ransack

I have a City Model:

```rb
    class Geo::City < Smth
      self.table_name = 'cities_table'
      has_many :streets, class_name: "Geo::Street", primary_key: :geo_code, foreign_key: :geo_code
```

The aim is, to search all streets in the city and print them as a search result. In my controller I have a filter method as follows:

```rb
    def filter
      @city_list = city_list
      params[:q] ||= {}
      params[:q][:ags8_id_eq] = @city_list[0][1]
      if params[:q].present? && params[:q][:geo_code_eq].present?
        @city = Geo::City.find_by(geo_code: params[:q][:geo_code_eq]) 
        @collection = [["#{@city}", "#{params[:q][:geo_code_eq]}"]]
      end
      @streets = @city.streets.limit(15)
      @q = @streets.ransack(params[:q])
    end
```

I also have a search_city method as follows:

```rb
  def search_city
    render json: city_list.select {|city| city.first.include?(params[:q][:geo_code_eq])}
  end
```

And a private method city_list which I am calling in methods above:

```rb
  def city_list
    all_cities = Geo::City.order('city_name').reduce([]) {|cities, c| cities << [c.name, c.geo_code]}
```

I had to change all the method names,cause it's for work, so the_city list is kind of an example and it also works fine, I assume, this is not the problem. I also have a js-file for select 2.

```js
    (function() {
      $(function() {
        return $('.city-select2').select2({
          ajax: {
            url: "/filter/search_city",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
            q: {
              geo_code_eq: params.term
            }
          };
            },
            processResults: function(data) {
              return {
                results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                  return {
                    id: obj[1],
                    text: obj[0]
                  };
                })
              };
            },
            cache: true
          },
          minimumInputLength: 2,
          placeholder: "City",
          tags: false,
          tokenSeparators: [","],
          selectOnClose: true,
          allowClear: true
        });
      });
    
    }).call(this);
```

It seems to be working, cause when I type city name it finds the city with the letters I typed. What happens after I submit select form is that I just get an empty array, so basically like this:
[image]

The url looks the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/filter/search_city?q%5Bgeo_code_eq%5D=16071003&commit=Search
```

My view does this:

```
= search_form_for @q, url: search_city_path do |f|
    .columns.is-centered{style: 'padding-top: 100px;'}
        .column.is-half
            = f.select(:geo_code_eq, options_for_select(collection: @collection.present? ? @collection : [], input_html: { class: "city-select2 select-input" })
            = f.submit "Search"
```

What is wrong? How do I get streets in the cities printed? There might be some spelling mistakes in the code, as I had to replace names, this won't be the reason for my empty array. Also, in the url there is only B selected, maybe that the reason? But it also finds the geo_code, so it should be capable of giving the streets back linked to geo_code, as geo_code is also the part of streets_table..

Answer (score 0):

Main reason for the array was the path in the view. Should have been filter_path ans not the search_city_path, as it was the same path my select2 was getting data from, redirection there on submit made no sence.